sample one node from each graph in a batch with pytorch
I am working with pygeometirc Batch objects. But, for those unfamiliar with it, I will pose my question as follows:
I am given a 1d tensor Y and a 1d tensor batch.
Y has the shape (num_of_nodes, ) and is the nodes' probabilities concatenated over the different graphs.
batch has the shape (num_of_nodes, ) and specifies the graph from which each node comes. Example:
Y = [0.2, 0.8, 1.]
batch = [0, 0, 1]
The first two nodes come from the first graph and the last from the second graph in the batch. Note that batch is always sorted.
I want to sample one node from each graph in the batch in a vectorized way. I am aware of a sequential way by splitting the vector and creating Categorical distributions, but this is too inefficient.
Example output:
out = [0, 2] or out = [1, 2]
Restarting the count at each graph (out=[0, 0] or out=[1, 0]) is fine, but not desirable.

This question is better suited for StackOverflow has it is more about coding rather than AI per se, but I did something like this recently, so here is what I ended up with:
First, you generate a random scalar for each node, then you identify the maximum value for each graph. This will point to a random node, one per graph. Here is a rough sketch:

Randomly sample a vector $z \sim U(0, 1) \in \mathbb{R}^N$, with $N$ being the number of nodes
Perform scatter with max-reduction: graph_choose = scatter(z, batch, reduction='max')
Perform gather: graph_choose = graph_choose[batch]
Compare the random vector with the graph-maximums: choice_mask = z == graph_choose. choice_mask will have a single True entry per graph, which is your randomly selected node.
(optionally) Apply mask to collect the random nodes the nodes: X_select = X[choice_mask]


Thank you so much. Choosing the maximum over uniform distributions should lead to a Discrete Uniform distribution over the nodes. Nonetheless, I'm not looking for a DUniform. I have the sampling probabilities given to me for each node. Are you aware of a sampling method that uses the same logic you used by perhaps augmenting z by p (given probabilities).

I tried multiplying z*p element-wise and choosing the maximum. Nonetheless, this proved to be mathematically wrong.

Ah, I misread, sry. Yes, you can extend the method to probabilities. Instead of the uniform distribution, you can use a Gumbel distribution: 1) Convert your probabilities to logits 2) sample a vector from the Gumbel distribution centered at your logits G(<your logits>, 1), continue with step 2) of my answer. This should work as the Gumbel distribution can be used as a substitute for categorical sampling.

I'll leave this here for any future reader: https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0030

Nice, I hope this question will not be closed, I will update my answer later and also reference this article :)
